# allow usb debugging not showing up

Tags: android, debugging, adb

I have Prestigio pmt3777_3g tablet running android 5.1.1.
I need to run usb debug mode but "Allow usb debugging" dialog doesn't show up when I use adb.

- I have enabled developer mode and usb debugging on tablet.
- I have changed usb connection stetting between charging/MTP/PTP.
- I run windows 8.1.
- I have latest android sdk.
- I have tried to use adb kill-server/start-server sequence.
- When I execute adb devices it returns empty list and no popup on
  tablet.

I know that everything is configured ok on PC because my Samsung S5 runs as expected on adb devices I get popup on phone and later I see my device in device list in CMD.

So I guess there is something wrong with my tablet (I have tried to reset to factory settings - this did not help).

Can anyone point something else that I can try force "Allow usb debugging" popup on my tablet?

Comment: http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2014/11/adb-device-detection-in-windows.html